# package installations are very slow in docker build

Tags: 16.04, proxy, docker

I've created a 16.04 ubuntu in docker, but installing the packages taking **too much time**. working behind corporate proxy, can someone help me with it.

tried in 14.04 version also, same speed. but the images are downloaded in seconds(72MB).

Answer (score 4):

This is probably related to the `ulimit` for `nofile`.

You can check what your container get by running

```
docker run ubuntu:16.04 bash -c "ulimit -n"
```

Set this during build/run with

```
docker run --ulimit nofile=1024 ...
docker build --ulimit nofile=1024 ...
```

Or configure your docker daemon as described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/).

I would recommend 1024 as a good starting point.
Tweak to your personal needs.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit

> Note that there is a bug that preventes you from setting the `default-ulimits` in the `daemon.json` file prior to Docker 1.13.
>   You need to use the --default-ulimits command line option when launching the daemon for docker versions prior to 1.13.

Comment: did not work for me :(

Comment: @Anand What is your ulimit in the container and what kind of issues are you seeing when setting the nofile ulimit?
The issue I saw was that the time was increasing with each package during `apt install` until it took minutes for a package to be installed. If you are seeing something different the root cause might not be the ulimit.

Comment: Ran into this issue on an AWS instance. I've tried raising ulimit, did not help much

Answer (score 1):

I just restart docker and everything works fine

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with a different installer. Worked for me in case of GatsbyJS, where I used yarn instead of npm and it became a bit fast.